# how to use excanvas in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, excanvas

I am using excanvas to draw graphical shape and below is my code. While calling the `.getContext("2d")` method it show the `'undefined'` exception in IE7 and IE8.

JS

```
 var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'http://canvas-text.googlecode.com/svn-history/r48/trunk/excanvas.js';
                script.type = 'text/javascript';

                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                context = c.getContext("2d");// getContext is undefined
```

html

```
  <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

What I did wrong.. anyone could help on this please?

Comment: `context = ('getContext' in c ) && c.getContext("2d");` then goes your code `if ( context ) { ..here your code goes. }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c= G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(c);
context = c.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: G_vmlCanvasManager this is also undefined.

Comment: It means that excanvas.js script is not loaded. Try the step suggested by "Ken Fyrstenberg"

Answer (score 1):

You must insert your script element into the DOM tree or it won't be parsed:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

(or wherever you want to attach it).

although, I would recommend just using a regular `<script>` tag when using excanvas and libraries that parses the DOM.